# How can I find the logarithmic function of my graph?

Tags: functions, logarithms

I am investigating this graph and I need to define it somehow. I know i could probably make a linear line through it but a logarithmic one would be better for the assignment. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange polynomial? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: I am not :(( I need something more simple, I'm doing the IB mathematics standard level.

Comment: In that case, just connect each two points with a straight line

Comment: @VojtaBroz Do you have the coordinates? You can then use Desmos which automatically fits a curve for you.

Comment: Hey Toby, I need to know how to get to the curve rather then getting it directly.

Comment: @VojtaBroz Can you please explain what you mean by 'how to get to the curve'?

Comment: If you're doing this for a course, don't you have any teaching materials to tell you how to do it? or, a teacher you can ask for help?

Comment: Toby, I need to find the function of the curve. Should i use linear regression to just find the line of best fit?

Comment: @VojtaBroz It's your assignment, so you can choose whatever model you want (given the context you are working in). Once you decide on which type of fit you are using, you can use Desmos to get a linear fit, quadratic fit, logarithmic fit etc. as shown in [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3dmkjpa6qn).